# How can I finish my incomplete GPX tracks?

Tags: gpx, gps-track-editor, modify-interaction

I have some incomplete GPS recordings. For whatever reason, the tracks weren't recorded , so there are some gaps in it. I could easily use the satellite images using QGIS software.

So I would like know how can I get them in order to alter an recorded GPX tracks without losing the timestamps.
I want to:

- add tracks (track points)
- split tracks
- merge tracks
- add timestamps to manual added tracks/ track points based on the original ones
- snaps tracks / track points to features (mainly roads) in osm or google maps.
- export the altered records so that [geosetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en/) can read them flawless.

Comment: What recordings are you talking about ? Are you refer them the shapefile you got from GPS ?

Comment: I have incomplete gpx files, there are some location/records missing. I want to add those missing points manually.